# Making multiple Docker Machines accessible across local network. Linux & Mac

Tags: linux, macos, docker, docker-swarm

I know there are several questions similar to this, but as far as I can see there's not an answer for the setup that I can get to work, and as far as documentation goes I'm a bit lost.

My goal is to set up a linux development server on the local network which I can run multiple docker machines / containers on for each of our projects.

Ideally, I would create a docker-machine on the dev box, and then be able to access that from any of my local network machines. I can run docker on the linux box directly and access by publishing the ports, but I want to run multiple machines with different ip addresses so that we can have multiple VMs running (multiple projects).

I've looked at Docker Swarm and overlay networks and just not been able to find a single tutorial or set of instructions to get this sort of set up running.

So I have a dev box at 192.168.0.101 with docker-machine on. I want to create a new machine, run nginx on it, and then access nginx from another machine on the local network i..e http://192.168.99.1/ then set up another and access that too at say http://192.168.99.2/.

If anyone has managed to do this i'd be interested to know how.

One way I've been thinking about doing it, is running nginx on the local host on the dev box, and set up config rules to proxy to the local machines, unsure how well this would work (it works for web servers, but what if I want to ssh or bash into one of those machines, or if one has a mysql container I want to connect to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I resolved this, is by using a NAT on the linux box, and then assigning a different ip to each machine. I followed the instructions here; http://blog.oddbit.com/2014/08/11/four-ways-to-connect-a-docker/ which finally got me to be able to share multiple docker machines using the same ports (80), on different ips.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered running your docker machines inside LXD containers?
Stepane Grabers site has a lot of relevant information
https://stgraber.org/category/lxd/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Could you point me in the direction of what it actually is or how I might use it for my particular scenario? i.e. webservers/mysql etc That page seems to be some blog posts that are not related to what I'm doing. Also, are you suggesting this because this is just not possible with Docker?

Comment: A good basic explanation can be found here https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/ I personally use lxc containers in a web development scenario and used nginx configured as a reverse proxy as a front end to several containers. lxdoc looks like it will be helpful too https://github.com/lxdock/lxdock

Comment: Yeah I did think about using nginx as a proxy like this, but then I also wanted to be able to run multiple mysql boxes, redis boxes etc

Comment: Yeah I see that, I just lxd exec bash to access containers with no web server as per https://stgraber.org/2016/04/12/lxd-2-0-remote-hosts-and-container-migration-612/